# Wireless adapter (MediaTek MT7921) is not working after a reboot in Ubuntu 21.10 (probe failed with error -110)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, asus

I have Ubuntu 21.10 and I've managed it to work with MediaTek MT7921 wireless adapter. However, just recently after rebooting my machine I can no longer use the adapter, it's just gone. I'm not sure, maybe it was caused by some of the updates. I've confirmed that adapter is working correctly in Windows 11 (dual-boot) so the problem is with Linux system.

---

#### `# lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

#### `# uname -a`

```
Linux kitcat 5.15.10-051510-generic #202112171031 SMP Fri Dec 17 10:53:39 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### `# lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:42:1a:86:25:37
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.10-051510-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf04000-fcf04fff memory:fcf00000-fcf03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fc30300000-fc303fffff memory:fc30400000-fc30403fff memory:fc30404000-fc30404fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: vethb9c79ff
       serial: 8a:d3:9e:7f:c7:71
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth4a60e92
       serial: 36:27:65:ec:c2:30
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: b6:1e:40:df:cb:07
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.10-051510-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.26.197 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

#### `# dmesg | grep mt7921`

```
[   15.142556] mt7921e 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   15.143067] mt7921e 0000:05:00.0: disabling ASPM  L1
[   15.143127] mt7921e 0000:05:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[   16.226929] mt7921e: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110
```

#### `# lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex [1022:1630]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir Root Complex [1043:16c2]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU [1022:1631]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir IOMMU [1043:16c2]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1633]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:02.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1634]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1632]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus [1022:1635]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH SMBus Controller [1043:16c2]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH LPC Bridge [1043:16c2]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166a]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166b]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166c]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166d]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166e]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:166f]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1670]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1671]
01:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch [1002:1478] (rev c3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch [1002:1479]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT / 6800M] [1002:73df] (rev c3)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT / 6800M] [1043:133c]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT] [1002:ab28]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:133c]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:208f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169


05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel modules: mt7921e


06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1aa] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:390f]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [1002:1638] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cezanne [1043:133c]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
07:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:133c]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
07:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1043:16c2]
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
07:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir USB 3.1 [1043:201f]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
07:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 [1022:1639]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir USB 3.1 [1043:201f]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
07:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1043:103f]
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x
07:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    DeviceName: HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1043:103f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

#### `# rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

#### `# apt info linux-firmware -a | grep Version`

```
Version: 1.201.3
Version: 1.201
```

#### `# lsmod | grep mt7921`

```
mt7921e                90112  0
mt76_connac_lib        49152  1 mt7921e
mt76                   86016  2 mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
mac80211             1228800  3 mt76,mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
cfg80211              962560  4 mt76,mt7921e,mac80211,mt76_connac_lib
```

#### `# modinfo mt7921e | grep -i version`

```
srcversion:     3E83D2B2F561C5689CE69C0
vermagic:       5.15.10-051510-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

#### `# dkms status`

```
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.12.19-051219-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.14.21-051421-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.15.10-051510-generic, x86_64: installed
```

What could be a reason for this? I will be happy to provide more details on first request.

Answer (score 2):

[patch from mediatek for reboot problem](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/patch/70e27cbc652cbdb78277b9c691a3a5ba02653afb.1641540175.git.objelf@gmail.com/)

This works for my asus zephyrus, hope will be mainline soon.

Comment: Just a link to a patch is problematic for future visitors. How can they know when it actually ships with the Ubuntu version they installed?

Comment: Wow! Looking forward for it to be merged, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## mt7921e probe failed with error -110

The error message that could be observed in `dmesg` is key here:

`mt7921e: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110`.

A very similar problem was [reported before](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205299) for `iwlwifi`.

It looks like dual booting with Windows causes this problem to appear. Windows is probably putting the network adapter into some state, that can't be recovered by Linux kernel driver and causes a time-out error.

Many have reported that this could be fixed by disabling the fast boot in Windows, but in my case it didn't help.

## Solution

The only way I found to make the adapter work is to completely **Power Off** the Windows instead of using a **Reboot**. When cold boot is initiated, the adapter could be initialized correctly by Linux kernel.

---

If you know a more permanent solution to this issue, please, share your ideas as well.

Comment: I encountered the same and for me, the funny solution was to turn off and start the laptop from battery. This would reliably detect the device.

Comment: I second @JohannesMariaFrank's experience. Nothing else works. After booting into Windows, my Ubuntu 21.10 with kernel 5.13.0-22 exhibits this symptom. The only way to get it to work again is to turn the computer off, unplug the charger, then boot into Linux. Then I can plug it back in and the problem doesn't happen again until I boot into Windows, when I have to perform this ritual again. I tried all other things I found on the Internet, including pcie_aspm=force. with no luck. My computer is a Asus Vivobook 16X OLED. Besides that, everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: There is a factory reset mechanism, at least on my ASUS: occasionally my wi-fi adapter stops to work entirely (both on Windows and Linux), in this case you need to hold the power button for a prolonged time. This will reset the BIOS settings though, but the adapter will be also reset and will start to work.