# My wireless disconnects constantly - mediatek Mt7921e

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

On Kubuntu 21.10: PCIe WiFi card, after many attempts to get the driver loaded and the adapter recognized I experience loops trying to connect (actually unable to open any page after connecting briefly and disconnecting). Sometimes it works briefly.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
        Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
        Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
        Kernel modules: mt7921e
    gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo dmesg | grep mt7
    [sudo] password for gianluca: 
    [    4.665793] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    4.665958] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM  L1
    [    4.665994] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
    [    4.745178] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20211014150838a
    [    5.004018] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20211014150922
    [    5.030282] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware init done
    [    7.367478] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
        Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
        Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
        Kernel modules: mt7921e
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo dmesg | grep mt7
[sudo] password for gianluca: 
[    4.621365] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.621499] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM  L1
[    4.621533] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    4.705334] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20211014150838a
[    4.964104] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20211014150922
[    4.990530] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware init done
[    7.325818] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
$ nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
eno1             ethernet  unavailable  --         
enp4s0           ethernet  unavailable  --         
enxf01e341f94c3  ethernet  unavailable  --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --         
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlp
[sudo] password for gianluca: 
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep mt7
[sudo] password for gianluca: 
[    4.604185] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.605051] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM  L1
[    4.605153] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    5.679912] mt7921e: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -110
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep 03:00
[sudo] password for gianluca: 
[    0.348217] pci 0000:03:00.0: [14c3:0608] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.348266] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xe0300000-0xe03fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.348309] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xe0400000-0xe0403fff 64bit pref]
[    0.348352] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xe0404000-0xe0404fff 64bit pref]
[    0.348483] pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.348483] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    4.713857] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.714308] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: disabling ASPM  L1
[    4.714386] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    5.792318] mt7921e: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: Please try my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: thanks. after doing this sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/* and reboot. card not detected

Comment: Check: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7`

Comment: done. could it have anything to do with the usb adapter I'm using as well? it seems the mt7 doesn't worlk when I boot, so I plug in the USB tp link, then I disconnect the usb and reconnect the mt7....sometimes it works this way. just chancing the question

Comment: Your readings look entirely normal. Please boot without the USB and show us: `nmcli d ` and: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: done without USB dongle. The mt7 was not detected after reboot.

Comment: Does it spring to life if you do: `sudo modprobe mt7921e` ?

Comment: no it doesn't come on

Comment: Does this tell us anything? `sudo dmesg | grep mt7`?

Comment: maybe a fatal error?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382918/wireless-adapter-mediatek-mt7921-is-not-working-after-a-reboot-in-ubuntu-21-10 Is this a dual-boot with Windows? Please disable Fast Boot: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: no it is not a dual boot system. kubuntu 21.10  only. sometimes adapter recognized, sometimes not and all modprobe commands don't change anything.

Comment: maybe something I need to change in BIOS? although  it's configured as default

Comment: Does it matter whether you rebbot or shut down entirely and start fresh?

Comment: mixed. randomly does it. very bizarre

Comment: When you boot and it is not working, please run: `sudo dmesg | grep 03:00` 03:00 is the PCI bus where the wireless resides. I am beginning to suspect hardware failure.

Comment: done. it was fine once, then updated, rebooted and not detected...and ran that command

Comment: then shut down, restarted and fine (not dual boot system)

Comment: I notice that this only appears in *dmesg* when the wireless is *not* working. "PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold " Please check in your BIOS/EFI and see if there are any settings related to D1, D2, etc. and tell me what they are. Possibly helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/supporting-d3cold-in-a-driver

Comment: ok I did check. No settings related to those. I checked every single line. Must say it seems like if I reboot the adapter is not detected; if I cold boot, it is. Again, this is a Linux system only )I'm awar of this issue on dual booting systems). I had installed win10 after I noticed this problem, just to check if the adapter was working: I kept it a few days and everything was fine. Then I installed kubuntu 21.10 again and posted the threads.

Comment: I regret that I am out of any useful suggestions except to *never* reboot and *always* cold boot. Aslo, I suggest that you file a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu I'm sorry that I could not be of more help.

Comment: I posted also on the manufacturer site. they say there's no available linux driver at the moment for the adapter (they say it's a 7921K). You've given fantastic help, without you I wouldn't even been able to use the wifi on this rig. I appreciate it very much. thanks chili555