# Mediatek Network Driver Unclaimed on 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 but the motherboard integrated wireless controller is listed as unclaimed

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:f80-f7f memory:f802100000-f8021fffff memory:fc800000-fc807fff
```

`lspci` lists it as

`0d:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616`

And running `modinfo mt7921e | grep alias` seems to indicate that the MediaTek driver have Device 0616 covered:

```
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

`dmesg` however does list this tidbit:

```
[    8.742395] mt7921e 0000:0d:00.0: Message 2000008a (seq 2) timeout
[    8.742477] mt7921e: probe of 0000:0d:00.0 failed with error -110
```

So is this an outdated kernel version problem, as some of the other similar cases are? Or is this a hardware problem? It literally worked two minutes ago on a temporary Windows installation (that I have since deleted) so I doubt it's bad hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what went wrong. Turns out according to [Wireless adapter (MediaTek MT7921) is not working after a reboot in Ubuntu 21.10 (probe failed with error -110)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382918/wireless-adapter-mediatek-mt7921-is-not-working-after-a-reboot-in-ubuntu-21-10), Windows will set the network controller into a strange state which Linux drivers cannot recover from. Since I had already deleted the Windows partition, taking out the CMOS battery on the motherboard and shorting the reset pins will do.